# Change ps -eo Separator but Retain Spaces in cmd Column

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

I have the following command that gathers a specific set of commands and narrows down the fields;

```
ps -eo euser,pid,start_time,etimes,cmd | grep -e "magento" | grep -v grep
```

And this is what I get;

```
root       89070 06:11   58310 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.website.update --single-thread --max-messages=20000
root       89072 06:11   58310 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.mass.update --single-thread --max-messages=20000
```

When shelled in, this is fine and displays what I need. However, I would like to change the separator to something else like a comma, pipe or other character not used in the output.

I tried an `awk` solution as such;

```
ps -eo euser,pid,start_time,etimes,cmd | awk NF=NF OFS=',' | grep -e "magento" | grep -v grep
```

And I get this as the output;

```
root,89070,06:11,58710,/usr/local/bin/php,/var/www/html/bin/magento,queue:consumers:start,product_action_attribute.website.update,--single-thread,--max-messages=20000
root,89072,06:11,58710,/usr/local/bin/php,/var/www/html/bin/magento,queue:consumers:start,inventory.mass.update,--single-thread,--max-messages=20000
```

The `cmd` column should have the spaces in there since that's the command being run and I need that particular information so I can transform it in a New Relic Flex integration. I've found that consistency in the data is generally ideal and it makes the streamed data present as expected.

I really need the output to look something like this;

```
root,89070,06:11,58710,/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.website.update --single-thread --max-messages=20000
root,89072,06:11,58710,/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start inventory.mass.update --single-thread --max-messages=20000
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to get there. I would prefer a one line solution, but if a script is needed that's also okay. I have `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, `perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`, and `Python 3.10.6` at my disposal.

[edit] The answer provided returned precisely what I needed with one exception, I need it in rows so this is what I'm using in case anyone comes across a similar issue later on;

```
ps -eo euser,pid,start_time,etimes,cmd | awk -v NF=NF '/[m]agento/{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (i<5) printf "%s,", $i
        else printf "%s ", $i
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    i==(NF-1){print ""}'
```

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same logic, you need:

```
ps -eo euser,pid,start_time,etimes,cmd | 
    awk -v NF=NF '
        /[m]agento/{
            for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (i<5) printf "%s,", $i
                else printf "%s ", $i
            }
        }
        i==(NF-1){print ""}
' file
```

Comment: I'm still not quite getting the output I need. I either have no commas and it's back to spaces, which will cause some issues with New Relic, or I still get the second output with commas between the commands. I need the comma separator between each column, but removed through the cmd column.

Comment: Post edited accordingly, please refresh and try again.

Comment: Came out swimmingly. Thanks a bunch!